# soundcloud player reseting on hash change in firefox?

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

I'm using the custom Jquery sound cloud player on my website. I've created a custom skin and it was working fine until I started using my navigation which changes the hash tag in the url e.g. #/blog

When the # changes in the url the player re load the track it is playing and I'm really not sure why this is happening? Also, It only happens in Firefox..

Any ideas?

Sorry it's a bit vague!

Alex

Comment: or a link to the page in question.

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML5 or the Flash-based widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up your copy of sc-player.js and find any reference such as href="# — then change those hrefs to javascript:void(0). Example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sc-info-toggle">Info</a>
```

The buttons still function, but now do not append/rewrite the hash.